# Android Facebook Feed Dialog Closes out when sharing

Tags: android, facebook, share

So I am trying to get Facebook's Feed dialog to pop up but right as I have it pop up it closes out like it fails or something. By the way I am only dealing with facebook if their application is installed. I don't want to share with them unless they are installed.

Here is where I'm going off of: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/

integrated with this a little for the authorization and logging in:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/native-login/

Here is my code:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

public void sendToFacebook()
{
if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
    List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
        pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                .NewPermissionsRequest(activity, PERMISSIONS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        return;
    }
    final Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString(NAME, app name);
    parameters.putString(LINK, info);
    parameters.putString(PICTURE, picture link);
    parameters.putString(CAPTION, "caption stuff");
    parameters.putString(DESCRIPTION, "description");

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            WebDialog feedDialog = (
                    new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(activity,
                        Session.getActiveSession(),
                        parameters))
                    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                            FacebookException error) {
                            //do something
                        }

                    })
                    .build();
                feedDialog.show();
        }
    });

    }else{
        initFacebookEngine(); //inits or opens the session. 
    }
    }

    private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
        for (String string : subset) {
            if (!superset.contains(string)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void initFacebookEngine() {
    if(session == null){
        session = new Session.Builder(ctx).build();
    }
    if(!session.isOpened() || !session.isClosed()){

         session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(activity)
            .setPermissions(PERMISSIONS)
            .setCallback(callback));
    }else{
        Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, callback);
    }
```

I call the method sendToFacebook. The callback merely calls sendToFacebook when called. The code will do the authentication stuff and permission but the feed dialog will not show its face. Facebook will act like it is doing something but then finish and come back to my app. Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Please, post your Manifest, String.xml and your app name, probably they not match.